# Pulling Out Value from Within Two-Levels Deep Object

Tags: javascript, parsing, typescript

I am trying to retrieve one particular value from within a two-levels deep object data structure. First off, though, I am saving into a variable within the function, like this:

```
getTargetId() {
    if (this.authenticationService.isAuthenticated()) {
        const userInfo = sessionStorage.getItem('currentUser');
        console.log(userInfo);
    }
}
```

From:

```
console.log(userInfo);
```

I get this back in the console:

```
{"token":"sometoken.value","data":{"_id":"8cd0362c0", "phone":"555-4343"...}
```

What I want to do is specifically pull out the "_id" value here.

I tried:

console.log(userInfo.data._id);

But then my IDE is showing me an error:

> 'Property '_id' does not exist on type 'string'.

How do I dig out "_id" in this case?

Comment: ...it's `userInfo.data._id`. Why did you think `this` had those properties?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access / process (nested) objects, arrays or JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/access-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json)

Comment: I provided additional info above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are accessing it wrong
Try `userInfo.data._id`
In the log of your object you can see by the `{}` notation that `data` is another object, so after accessing `data` you can access its properties just as you would with any other object.

I also see that you are getting

> 'Property '_id' does not exist on type 'string'.

This could mean that you never parsed the information. To find out if this is the case this should be right:

Running->

```
console.log(userInfo);
```

Returns->

```
{"token":"sometoken.value","data":{"_id":"8cd0362c0", "phone":"555-4343"...}
```

Just after this code:
Running->

```
console.log(typeof userInfo);
```

Returns->

```
"string"
```

With your edits, I can see that this is the case.
Try:

```
userInfo = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('currentUser') );
console.log(userInfo.data._id);
```

Comment: This stil gets me this in my IDE:
'Property 'data' does not exist on type 'string'.

Comment: @Ademo then it seems like you need to `JSON.parse` that string.

Comment: The I guess you would need to post more code. If you ran the code `console.log(userInfo);` and got the object data, you should be able to run this `console.log(userInfo.data._id);` and get the id. If it doesn't work, you are changing the variable somewhere else

Comment: Yeah, @jonrsharpe could be right, may be you are trying to access the info before parsing it

Comment: Yup. I had just come to the same conclusion and had fixed it after reading the comment above from @jonsharpe. Will mark yours as correct rather than my own answer.

Answer (score 1):

The `_id` property is under the `data` key:

```js
const response = {
    "token":"sometoken.value",
    "data": {
       "_id":"8cd0362c0",
       "phone":"555-4343"
     }
};
console.log(response.data._id)
```

You can also use destructuring:

```
const { _id } = response.data;
console.log(_id)
```

or:

```
const { data: { _id }} = response;
console.log(_id);
```

Answer (score 1):

So, as @jonsharpe pointed out, the key was to JSON.parse the string first. So this gets me the value I need for "_id":

```
getTargetId() {
    if (this.authenticationService.isAuthenticated()) {
        const userInfo = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('currentUser'));
        console.log(userInfo.data._id);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually your string is returned as JSON string. So you have to parse it into object using **JSON.parse()** if you are using js or with **$.parseJSON()** if you are using Jquery. So your updated code now looks like this.

```js
var user ='{"token":"sometoken.value","data":{"_id":"8cd0362c0", "phone":"555-4343"}}';
var k = JSON.parse(user);
alert(k.data._id);
```

And Fiddle is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/1we15btb/).
Thank You